# como ajustar el contenido de una celda , que ocupe toda la celda

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

quiero que lo que este dentro de la celda se ajuste al contenido o que el contenido se ajuste a la celda

les mando la imagen de como esta :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como ven la imagen tto1linea no ocupa toda la celda, cuando modifico el tamaño de esta imagen,se pone mas chico pero queda mas espacio en la celda y yo quiero que se ajuste

mi codigo :

```
<table class="table table-hover"  id="pacientes" >
          <tr>   
              <th rowspan="2" style="text-align:center;">N°</th>
            <th rowspan="2" style="text-align:center;">E. TRATAMIENTO</th>
              <th rowspan="2" style="text-align:center;">N. DE CASO</th>
              <th rowspan="2" style="text-align:center;">F. INICIO</th>    
              <th rowspan="2" style="text-align:center;">DNI</th>
              <th rowspan="2" style="text-align:center;">NOMBRE</th>
              <th rowspan="2" style="text-align:center;">HUELLA</th>
            <th rowspan="2" style="text-align:center;">FACTORES</th>
            <th rowspan="2" style="text-align:center;">FASE</th>
            <th rowspan="2" style="text-align:center;">MES TTO</th>
              <th rowspan="2" colspan="2" style="text-align:center;">AMPLIACION</th>
            <th rowspan="2" align="center" ></th>
          </tr>
          <tr></tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <th colspan="1">INICIO</td>
            <th colspan="1">DOSIS</td>
          </tr>
          <?php 
            $i=1;

            while ($row = $resultado_personas->fetch_array())
            {
              ?>
              <tr>
                <td align="center" ><?php echo $i++; ?></td>
                 <td align="center" style="width: 18%;"><?php if($row['ttratamiento']=="TRATAMIENTO PRIMERA LINEA") { ?> <img src="../img/tt1linea.png" class="img-responsive"   style="width: 75%;" > <?php }else{ ?> <img   src="../img/tt2linea.png" class="img-responsive"  style="width: 75%;" > <?php }; ?></td>
                  <td align="center"><?php echo $row['nro_caso']; ?></td>   
                <td align="center"><?php echo $row['f_inicio']; ?></td>
                  <td align="center"><?php echo $row['dni']; ?></td>

                  <td><?php echo $row['apellidopaterno']." ".$row['apmaterno']." ".$row['nombre']." "; ?><a href="#" class="viw_dat_personal" id="<?php echo $row["dni"]; ?>"><?php if($row['sexo']=='1'){ ?> <i class="fa fa-male fa-2x " aria-hidden="true"></i> <?php }else { ?> <i class="fa fa-female fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" style="
    color: #ff9cae;"></i> <?php  } ?>  </a></td>
                  <td align="center"><?php if($row['dnihu']!==null){ ?> <img src="../img/huella_si.png"> <?php ; } ; ?></td>
                <td class="text-center"> 
                  <?php
                    $factores = "SELECT tif.`Tif_Nombre`, tif.`Tif_Icono` FROM factor_riesgo far INNER JOIN tipo_factor tif ON tif.`Tif_IdTipoFactor` = far.`Tif_IdTipoFactor` WHERE cod_det_pac_tra = '".$row['codigodet']."'";

                    $resultado_factores = mysqli_query($conexion, $factores) or mysql_error($conexion);

                    while($fila_factor = $resultado_factores->fetch_array())
                    {
                      ?>
                        <a href="" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $fila_factor['Tif_Nombre']?>"><img src="../img/icono/<?php echo $fila_factor['Tif_Icono']?>"></a>
                      <?php
                    }

                  ?>
                </td>
                <td align="center"><?php echo $row['fase']; ?></td>
                <td align="center"><?php echo convertir_mes($row['cantidad_asis']); ?></td>
                  <td colspan="1" align="center"><?php echo  $row['amp_fechini']; ?></td>
                <td colspan="1" align="center"><?php echo $row['cntidad_amp']; ?></td>
                <td colspan="1" align="center">
                   <a href="#"   dni="<?php echo $row['dni']; ?>" for="<?php echo $row["ttratamiento"]; ?>" name="control" id="<?php echo $row["codigodet"]; ?>" class="ctrldata" ><img src="../img/control.png"  alt=""  style="width: 20%; min-width: 20px;"></a>
                  <a href="#"  name="ver" id="<?php echo $row["codigodet"]; ?>" class="viw_data" ><img  id="calendario"  src="../img/calendario.png" style="width: 20%; min-width: 20px;"></a>

                  <?php 
                    if($tipo_usuario != 1) 
                    { 
                      ?>   
                        <a href="#" name="egreso"    id="<?php echo $row["codigodet"]; ?>" class="egreso" ><img id="calendario" src="../img/EGRESO.png" style="width: 20%; min-width: 20px; "  ></a>
                      <?php 
                    }
                    ?>

                    <?php 
                    if($tipo_usuario == 1) 
                    { 
                      ?> 
                       <a class="btn btn-danger btn-md eliminar_resultado" id="<?php echo $row["dni"]; ?>" title="Eliminar"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                      <?php 
                    }
                  ?> 
                </td>
              </tr>
              <?php
            } 
          ?>
        </table>
```

Comment: Y ya probaste simplemente dándole un width:100% a la imagen ?

Comment: si, el problema es que quiero disminuir el tamaño de la imagen y cuandohago eso me deja espacios, y no disminuye el tamaño de la celda

Answer (score 1):

En tu tabla tienes un error de estructura que aunque visualmente funciona igual dentro del código es un error como tal, te faltan las secciones de tabla `<thead>` y `<tbody>`

```
<table>
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Ahora para el problema que tienes con el tamaño de tu `img` y tu `td` podrías intentar lo siguiente:

```
<td style="width: 50px">
    <img src="../img/tt1linea.png" class="img-responsive" style="width: 100%;">
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Dale mas ancho a la celda de fecha ya que esa es la culpable de que toda la fila tenga mas altura porque la fecha ocupa dos lineas, dale mas ancho y con eso lo solucionas

Answer (score 1):

Aplica anchos a los **th**

```
<tr>   
    <th rowspan="2" style="text-align:center; width:5%">N°</th>
    <th rowspan="2" style="text-align:center; width:10%">E. TRATAMIENTO</th>
    <th rowspan="2" style="text-align:center; width:10%">N. DE CASO</th>
    <th rowspan="2" style="text-align:center; width:20%">F. INICIO</th> 
</tr>
```

Vas ajustando los porcentajes hasta obtener el resultado deseado.

Y reemplaza las imágenes por botones:

```
<img src="../img/tt1linea.png" class="img-responsive"   style="width: 75%;" >
<img src="../img/tt2linea.png" class="img-responsive"   style="width: 75%;" >
```

Botones **Bootstrap** de ejemplo:

```
<button class="btn btn-block btn-success">TTO 1 LÍNEA</button>
<button class="btn btn-block btn-danger">TTO 2 LÍNEA</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Debe tener en cuidado con el uso de `colspan` dado que el valor de referencia de celdas equivale al `tr` que tenga más `td`'s adentro.

**Ejemplo:** aqui el colspan maximo es 3

```html
<table>
<style>table,tr,td { border: 1px solid black;}</style>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>foo</td><td>bar</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>foo</td><td>bar</td><td>beer</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>foo</td><td>bar</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Usando colspan:** Para ajustar el contenido de los `td` con valor "bar" del ultimo y final debo aplicar `colspan="1"` al primer `td` y `colspan="2"` al segundo; dando un total de `3`.

```html
<table>
<style>table,tr,td { border: 1px solid black;}</style>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="1">foo</td>
    <td colspan="2">bar</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>foo</td><td>bar</td><td>beer</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="1">foo</td>
    <td colspan="2">bar</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Error al usar colspan:** cuando trabajas con un for, y tratas todos los `td` igual puede ocurrir que un dato no exista y por ende se cambia el máximo `colspan` o que exista un dato de más.

```html
<table>
<style>table,tr,td { border: 1px solid black;}</style>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="1">foo</td>
    <td colspan="2">bar</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="1">foo</td>
    <td colspan="2">bar</td>
    <td>beer</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="1">foo</td>
    <td colspan="2">bar</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Para el caso anterior, el col span maximo es de 4 dado que aplico.

```
<td colspan="1">  // +1 max colspan 1
<td colspan="2">  // +2 ahora max colspan  3
<td >  // defecto es +1 osea ahora max colspan  4
```

**Como ajustar las Columnas de una tabla:** para lograrlo tienes 2 opciones usar con mas cuidad los `colspan` o usar **solo** atributos de css  `width, max-width,min-width` y digo solo, porque a diferencia de los `colspan` los estilos css se heredan en cascada, aplicando a todos sus `hermanos paralelos` por decirlo así el ultimo atributo css aplicado teniendo prioridad `min-width` sobre `max-width` y este sobre `width` .

A continuación un ejemplo donde aplico 50px de ancho, luego digo que el min de ancho sea 150px , pero intento aplicar 20px en ancho y maximo ancho.

```html
<table style="width:300px">
  <style>table,tr,td { border: 1px solid black;}</style>
  <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="width:50px">foo</td>
        <td style="width:50px">bar</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>foo</td>
        <td>bar</td>
        <td>beer</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>foo</td>
        <td style="min-width:150px;width:50px;max-width:20px;" >bar</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>foo</td>
        <td>bar</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con el siguiente codigo.

```
 <!-- 2 --> <td colspan="1" align="center" style=""><img src="../img/tt1linea.png" class="img-responsive"   style="width: 100" ></td>
```

Aunque la mejor solución es editar las imágenes para que tengan el mismo tamaño, preocuparse por aplicar `HACKS` para "maquillar" errores come tiempo, cuando puedes corregir la fuentes del error. "osea imágenes de distinto tamaño".

Ahora también tu código tiene un error en columnas, prueba con el siguiente código:

```html
<table class="table table-hover"  id="pacientes" >
<style>  tr, td , th { border:1px solid red;}</style>
              <!-- CREA TITULOS EL SON 12 th pero el COLSPAN ES DE 13 porque APLIACION vale 2-->
              <thead>
              <tr>   
              <!--1--><th rowspan="2" style="text-align:center;">N°</th>
                <!--2--> <th rowspan="2" style="text-align:center;">E. TRATAMIENTO</th>
              <!--3--> <th rowspan="2" style="text-align:center;">N. DE CASO</th>
              <!--4--> <th rowspan="2" style="text-align:center;">F. INICIO</th>    
              <!--5--> <th rowspan="2" style="text-align:center;">DNI</th>
              <!--6--> <th rowspan="2" style="text-align:center;">NOMBRE</th>
              <!--7--> <th rowspan="2" style="text-align:center;">HUELLA</th>
                <!--8--><th rowspan="2" style="text-align:center;">FACTORES</th>
                <!--9--><th rowspan="2" style="text-align:center;">FASE</th>
                <!--10--><th rowspan="2" style="text-align:center;">MES TTO</th>
              <!--11--> <th rowspan="2" colspan="2" style="text-align:center;">AMPLIACION</th>
                <!--12--> <th rowspan="2" align="center" >OPCIONES</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <!--1 AL 10--><td colspan="10"></td><!-- APLICO COLSPAN 10 RECUERDE EL MAX ES 13 -->
                <!--11:1--><th colspan="1">INICIO</td>
                <!--11:2--><th colspan="1">DOSIS</td>
                <!--12--><th></th>
              </tr>
              </thead>
              <?php 
                $i=1;
                $personas = [['nro_caso'=>'002', 'f_inicio'=>'2019-05-28', 'dni'=>'000', 'dnihu' => '111',
                              'apellidopaterno'=>'Foo','apmaterno'=>'bar', 'nombre'=>'beer',
                              'fase'=>'', 'cantidad_asis'=>'','amp_fechini'=>'2019-04-01', 'cntidad_amp'=>'100',
                              'ttratamiento'=>'TRATAMIENTO PRIMERA LINEA', 'codigodet'=>'9343']];
                 $tipo_usuario = 1;
                for ($j =0; $j < count($personas); $j++)
                {
                  $row = $personas[$j];
                  ?>
                  <tr>
                    <!-- 1 --><td colspan="1" align="center" ><?php echo $i++; ?></td>
                    <!-- 2 --><td colspan="1" align="center" style=""><?php if($row['ttratamiento']=="TRATAMIENTO PRIMERA LINEA") { ?> <img src="../img/tt1linea.png" class="img-responsive"   style="width: 85%;" > <?php }else{ ?> <img   src="../img/tt2linea.png" class="img-responsive"  style="width: 75%;" > <?php }; ?></td>
                   <!-- 3 --><td colspan="1" align="center"><?php echo $row['nro_caso']; ?></td>   
                    <!-- 4 --><td colspan="1"  align="center"><?php echo $row['f_inicio']; ?></td>
                   <!-- 5 --><td colspan="1" align="center"><?php echo $row['dni']; ?></td>
    
                   <!-- 6 --><td colspan="1" ><?php echo $row['apellidopaterno']." ".$row['apmaterno']." ".$row['nombre']." "; ?><a href="#" class="viw_dat_personal" id="<?php echo $row["dni"]; ?>"><?php if($row['sexo']=='1'){ ?> <i class="fa fa-male fa-2x " aria-hidden="true"></i> <?php }else { ?> <i class="fa fa-female fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" style="
        color: #ff9cae;"></i> <?php  } ?>  </a></td>
                   <!-- 7 --><td colspan="1" align="center"><?php if($row['dnihu']!==null){ ?> <img src="../img/huella_si.png"> <?php ; } ; ?></td>
                    <!-- 8 --><td colspan="1" class="text-center"> 
                      <?php
                        $factores = [['Tif_Nombre'=> 'TTO 33', 'Tif_Icono' => '']];
                        for($k = 0; $k < count($factores); $k++)
                        {
                          $fila_factor = $factores[$k];
                          ?>
                            <a href="" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $fila_factor['Tif_Nombre']?>"><img src="../img/icono/<?php echo $fila_factor['Tif_Icono']?>"></a>
                          <?php
                        }
    
                      ?>
                    </td>
                    <!-- 9 --><td colspan="1"  align="center"><?php echo $row['fase']; ?></td>
                    <!-- 10 :D --><td colspan="1"  align="center"><?php echo $row['cantidad_asis']; ?></td>
                   <!-- 11:1 --><td colspan="1" align="center"><?php echo  $row['amp_fechini']; ?></td>
                    <!-- 11:2--><td colspan="1" align="center"><?php echo $row['cntidad_amp']; ?></td>
                    <!-- 12--><td colspan="1" align="center">
                       <a href="#"   dni="<?php echo $row['dni']; ?>" for="<?php echo $row["ttratamiento"]; ?>" name="control" id="<?php echo $row["codigodet"]; ?>" class="ctrldata" ><img src="../img/control.png"  alt=""  style="width: 20%; min-width: 20px;"></a>
                      <a href="#"  name="ver" id="<?php echo $row["codigodet"]; ?>" class="viw_data" ><img  id="calendario"  src="../img/calendario.png" style="width: 20%; min-width: 20px;"></a>
           
                      <?php 
                        if($tipo_usuario != 1) 
                        { 
                          ?>   
                            <a href="#" name="egreso"    id="<?php echo $row["codigodet"]; ?>" class="egreso" ><img id="calendario" src="../img/EGRESO.png" style="width: 20%; min-width: 20px; "  ></a>
                          <?php 
                        }
                        ?>
                        
                        <?php 
                        if($tipo_usuario == 1) 
                        { 
                          ?> 
                           <a class="btn btn-danger btn-md eliminar_resultado" id="<?php echo $row["dni"]; ?>" title="Eliminar"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                          <?php 
                        }
                      ?> 
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <?php
                } 
              ?>
            </table>
```